# Does Watson Analytics has a limit on the number of records it can import from dashDB?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, dashdb

I have a account in IBM Watson Analytics (https://watson.analytics.ibmcloud.com).

I also have an account in IBM Public Bluemix. I provisioned a dashDB instance and inserted 10,000 records into a dashDB table. In Bluemix dashDB, I verified (via SQLs etc.) that the 10,000 records do exist in the dashDB table.

I configured a connection in Watson Analytics to connect to my Bluemix dashDB instance. But, when I try to view the data, Watson Analytics shows / allows for upload (when I click 'shape before upload') only 1000 records from the dashDB table.

Is this a limit enforced on Watson Analytics accounts ?

In Watson Analytics, in my account settings/info page, for subscription it says "BACC-IBM WA Professional" and for total space it says that I have used only 97 MB out of available 100 GB.  Also, it says that maximum upload size is 10 GB and the maximum number of columns allowed in your data asset is 500 columns. The data I have uploaded into dashDB was in total 1 GB for all of 10,000 records.

So, I do not understand why Watson Analytics is not able to show /allow for upload more than 1000 records from dashDB. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your account type will allow you to upload up to 10 million rows of data in a single data set.  The "shape before upload" view is just a preview of the data.  It does not allow you to page through the entire data set.  But it will upload your entire table.  You can confirm this by doing the following:

- Complete the upload of your table from dashDB.
- Click on the new data tile.  This opens a new discovery set.
- At the top where it says "Ask a question about your data", just type "count rows".
- Select the first visualization it suggests.

This will show the number of rows in a simple text visualization.